# Parent content-type is not displaying properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

For some reason, on this content-type which has the value of "SL Document" set as their parent in my content hub, it shows up like this in my Document Library content-type settings:

[image: Content-type with wrong parent]

If I then click on that parent link, it reloads into a page called "Site Content Types : Site Content-Type ", and the *correct* parent content-type of SL Document is listed.

Throughout all of this, my parent content-type's metadata column of "Classification" is missing in the document library. I have republished the parent a few times now, waited a day, and the "Classification" column is not coming through. In the screenshot, you can see that the column from the parent called "Keywords" (multi line type) *is* coming through. I am out of ideas here, and Microsoft Support has been looking into this for weeks now without any progress. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**We recommend that you perform the following troubleshootings:**

1.Add a new site column in the **parent content type(Site Content Type)**, please make sure whether to check the "**Update all content types inheriting from this type**" option.

[image]

2.If it still does not display, please go to the Document library and delete the content type, and then add it again.

[image]

3.If it still doesn’t work, I suggest you delete the **parent content type(Site Content Type)** and recreate it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried step 1 and 2, and the new test column from the parent, AND my problem column from the parent, did not show up on the content-type before and after removing and re-adding it

Unfortunately, I will not be able to delete the parent content type. It is being used on live sites already.

Comment: Hi Mysticode. This is indeed a very unusual phenomenon. I suggest you create a new site content type to see if similar problem occur.

Comment: I am working with Microsoft SharePoint engineers on this issue.